# My UITableViewCell will not delete

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, nsmutablearray

My UITableViewCell will not delete when I call the method.  I can get it to print out the cell it is supposed to delete, but it will not remove itself, and it won't remove itself from the array.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [customData removeObjectIdenticalTo:thisCell.textLabel.text];
    NSLog(@"%@", customData);
    [thisCell removeFromSuperview];
    [tabler reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need this: `[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];`